# how to catch exception of called function in calling function?

Tags: python, ssh, try-catch

Please have a look at the pseudo-code.
I am unable to catch exception in Scenario2

**Scenario 1:**
**A.py**

```
def fun1():
    try:
        ssh connection
        do something1
        do something2
        session.write(cmd1) # Execute some commands
        session.write(cmd2)
        session.write(cmd3)
        session.write(cmd4)
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print err
        Do something with err
        Further decision making based on err
```

**Scenario 2:**
**B.py**

```
def fun1():
    try:
        ssh connection
        do something1
        do something2
        execute_commands(session)
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print err
        Do something with err
        Further decision making based on err

def execute_commands(session):
    session.write(cmd1) # Execute some commands
    session.write(cmd2)
    session.write(cmd3)
    session.write(cmd4)
```

In A.py, There is only one function which does everything. I know that while executing cmd1 to cmd4, it throws runtime error. A.py absolutely works fine.
In B.py, I've created another separate function to execute those commands separately.But here I'm not able to catch that run time error.In B.py, as execute_commands() is called it hangs there. It doesn't catch any exceptions.
How do i catch the same exception occurred in fun1() when execute_commands() is called ?

```
import SSHLibrary
session = SSHLibrary.SSHLibrary()
            session.open_connection(self.ip, self.prompt)
            session.login(self.username, self.password)
session.write(cmd1)
session.read_until("some pattern")
```

Runtimerror causing because of pattern mismatch. So, handling it in exception block and processing it further.

Comment: If your `execute_command()` function is identical to what you mentioned in A.py, and the code in A.py works, it will work here as well. You MUST have made few other modifications

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri : Everything is same. Just two separate functions in B.py. Couldn't catch the RuntimeError of execute_commands() in fun1().

Comment: As a note since you mentioned *Format error* in `except` block: if you are parsing the stack-trace *string* it will fail here because now stack-trace will be different

Comment: hanging is not what happens when you have an uncaught exception -> hanging is a separate issue. Also, if you want assistance, show us how you're making your ssh connection and how you're executing commands.

Comment: Try printing the exact command (`print(repr(cmd1))` etc...) you are about to execute each time (and 'done' when the function completes). Make sure its `repr` so we can see any new lines. If the second hangs you know which command it is and can compare them. Do these commands have parameters? it could be that you use local variables in a.py but they arent there in b.py.

Comment: Please revise your question accordingly: You have an issue with your ssh connection hanging, not exceptions.

Comment: @TemporalWolf : I've edit the question along with snippet.